# Is $O(\log x) = O(1)$?

Tags: big-o-notation

A colleague recently brought up this argument when we were talking about big-O runtime analysis and I've been unable to find why it is incorrect:

Informally, the argument goes like this:

> "If the runtime of all logarithms of any base are supposed to be
> equivalent, there is nothing that keeps us from saying $O(\log x) \equiv O(\log_x x) \equiv O(1)$, so either the upper bound of
> logarithmic growth is constant (which it evidently is not) or all
> logarithms are, after all, not equal in runtime."

We recalled the reasoning behind the accepted $ O(\log_a x) \equiv O(\log_b x)$ from the lemma that allows us to calculate logarithms of arbitrary base, i.e.

$$
\log_a x = \frac{\log_b x}{\log_b a}
$$
where, since $a,b$ are constant also $\frac{1}{\log_b a}$ is constant, and hence  $ O(\log_a x) \equiv O(\log_b x)$  holds.

I argued that since $x$ is decidedly not a constant, his conjecture would also be false as no constant factor could be extracted from the lemma.

The counterargument quickly followed, stating that since $ O(\log_a x) \equiv O(\log_b x)$ holds  $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R^+}$ it must not only hold in $a =x$ or $b = x$, but <strike>also in $a=1$ and $b=1$ and consequently $ O(\log x) \equiv O(\log_1 x) = O(0) \equiv O(1)$ breaking the original lemma not only for the base $x$ but also base $1$, where $1$ is about as constant as it gets.</strike> <-  beer induced math fail

At that point in conceded that I could not find a flaw in the argumentation and as such I am turning to you: What's going on here and where are we wrong?

Comment: Was your friend invented for the sake of a homework exercise?

Comment: $\log_1 x$ is not defined: if you think it is, then $\log_1 x = \frac{\log_b x}{\log_b 1} = \frac{\log_b x}{0}$.

Comment: No we're both already past the stages of our lives where we do homework. Also thanks Nathaniel you are indeed correct there, I guess we both confused $log_1 x$ with $log 1$. Also for reference this argument took place after some drinks!

Answer (score 2):

Let me emphasize some flaws in argumentation:

1.

> $O(\log x) \equiv O(\log_x x)$

is false because on left hand base of logarithm is constant, but on right hand not.

2.

> $ O(\log_a x) \equiv O(\log_b x)$ holds  $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R^+}$

is false, because there should be additionally $a,b > 1.$

Answer (score 1):

Let's generalize the argument. It is well-known that $O(f(n)/C) = O(f(n))$. Now let $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be arbitrary functions. Then
$$ O(f(n)) = O(f(n)/f(n)) = O(1) = O(g(n)/g(n)) = O(g(n)). $$
What goes wrong here? We only have $O(f(n)/C) = O(f(n))$ for *constant* $C > 0$.

Similarly, we only have $O(\log_a n) = O(\log_b n)$ for *constant* $a,b>1$.